# Buying a 1981 Kawasaki 440 D questions

Tags: motorcycle, belt, drivetrain, kawasaki

There is a 1981 Kawasaki 440 D that is belt driven on Craigslist for $850 and I just have a few questions on about it being a belt drive. Is a belt drive ok to have? Is it worse than chain drive? And if I do decide to buy this bike and the belt breaks how easy would it be to find a replacement belt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Google search revealed  several sources for a replacement final drive belt. Getting a replacement should not be a problem. If the current belt is more than five years old or the  owner doesn't know how old it is I would replace it soon.  The advantages of belt drive are less maintenance, no lubricant is slung off, like on a chain and they are quieter. The disadvantages are they can be model specific, meaning unless it is a really popular model most shops won't stock it. Tensioning a belt requires a little more care than a chain. If you don't inspect it regularly it can fail with no warning.